# how to put reference in method argument not value python

Tags: reference

Hi i have code like this

```
a = 7

def Add(number):
         number+=1
         print(number)

Add(a) 
print(a)
```

and it prints

```
8
7
```

as I know it must to change it because function takes reference everytime in python whats problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Add` will not change the value of `a`. `number` in `Add` is a new copy object `a`. You can see here that they are different objects, use [`id(object)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) which returns object identifying number for `a` and `nuumber`:

```
a = 7

def Add(number):
    number+=1
    print("'number' id => {0}".format(id(number)))
    print(number)


print("'a' id => {0}".format(id(a)))
Add(a) 

print("'a' id => {0}".format(id(a)))
print(a)
```

output, identifiers might be different than yours:

```
'a' id => 19295200
'number' id => 19295188 <- different new object with different id
8
'a' id => 19295200
7
```

So any changes you apply on `number` will not effect `a`. Python way of doing it is to reassign the object with the new value:

```
a = 7

def Add(number):
         number+=1
         print(number)
         return number

a = Add(a) 
print(a)
```

output:

```
8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem, though i don't know what language is it, is that  you are sending to `add` function `number` by value, meaning that the value you are assigning to it at `number+=1` will not stay when you leave the function

for example, and because i don't know what language is it, i'll show you in c:

the same thing will happen if you do in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void add(int a)
{
    a += 1;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

main()
{
   int a = 7;
   add(a);
   printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

but if you'll send a pointer to the integer and change the value in the pointer the value will be changed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void add(int *a)
{
    *a += 1;
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}

main()
{
   int a = 7;
   add(&a);
   printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

the output is

```
8
8
```